# Pipe Python script to ssh, but do other bash commands first

Tags: python, bash, ssh, remote-execution

A very convenient way to execute a Python script on a remote server is to [pipe it to ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22915340/1397061):

```
cat script.py | ssh user@address.com python -
```

where the `-` seems to be optional.

**How can I execute other bash commands before running the Python script in this way?**

This does not work:

```
cat script.py | ssh user@address.com "cd ..; python -" # WRONG!
```

Interestingly, this sends a non-deterministically corrupted version of the Python script, which gives a syntax error in a different place every time you run it!

Comment: Tip: if you're using this method, use `python -u` for unbuffered output so stdout shows up immediately after printing.

Comment: Does the corruption always happen in the first few lines?

Comment: @YatharthROCK I don't remember, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a sub-shell:

```
cat script.py | ssh user@address.com "(cd ..; python -)"
```

Or a temporary file:

```
cat script.py | ssh user@address.com "tee >/tmp/tmp.py; cd ..; python /tmp/tmp.py; rm /tmp/tmp.py"
```

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure how to capture stdin.