# Use Jupyter Notebook on my local computer to run code on a remote computer

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I use Jupyter Notebook to run bioinformatic analyses, and I love it. However, it only really plays nice when I run it on my personal computer. However, I regularly do analysis using a remote computer with multiple cores to reduce processing time. I'd like to be able to use the Jupyter Notebook interface on my personal computer while everything is actually running on the remote computer. I generally do this via ssh access to the remote computer within the shell and execute all commands at the command line. I'd love to do this from the Jupyter notebook on my personal computer, rather than from the shell on my personal computer. It is relevant that I don't have sudo access on the remote computer.

So far, I've installed `miniconda` and `jupyter notebook` on the remote computer like this:

```
wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Once conda is installed properly, I install jupyter notebook via miniconda with this line:

```
conda install jupyter
```

This installs successfully. I can then start a jupyter notebook session on the remote machine with the line:

```
jupyter notebook --no-browser
```

So far, so good. My next question: How do I have my local jupyter notebook connect to the remote machine, so that I can execute commands on the remote machine using my local jupyter notebook? There is some documentation [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html), however i have been trying different things for hours, but have failed to succeed.

Can anyone give a straight forward method to connect to my remote server, given that I am this far along? I feel like it should just be a matter of entering url addresses and passwords into my local Jupyter notebook (all of this is so easy via ssh in the shell).

Comment: "This document describes how you can secure a notebook server and how to run it on a public interface."  The docs don't tell you how to connect a worker notebook that is remote to a master notebook running on your laptop.  What these docs do, is  tell you how to enable connecting to a remote jupyter notebook over the web from any web browser.  You access the remote notebook with any web browser, and will have access to the CPU and data on the remote computer.  If you need some files from the local computer, you will have to copy them manually to the remote computer.

Comment: @Paul thanks for that clarification!

Comment: I have yet to test this, but this may be relevant. https://coderwall.com/p/ohk6cg/remote-access-to-ipython-notebooks-via-ssh

Comment: @colin did you ever get an answer to this? I ask, as the two answers missed the point of running the notebook locally and performing remote execution.

Comment: @GregHilston nope, never got a good answer to this, and as you point out neither of the below answers address the core issue (though they are helpful!) As far as I can tell Jupyter notebooks just aren't a good solution for folks working across multiple computing environments.

Comment: I was also looking for the answer to this, but the more I thought about it, the more I realized I was asking "How do I run computation remotely from within Python?", because Jupyter is really just a fancy interpreter interface. I found some answers to how to do that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27412611/429596

Answer (score 6):

Follow the steps below:
Enable port forwarding on remote machine

```
ssh -N -f -L 127.0.0.1:8898:127.0.0.1:8898 user@remote-machine.com
```

Do `ssh` to your remote machine  and then run following command on remote machine

```
jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8898
```

you will see some thing as shown below

```
    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
http://localhost:8898/token=eaf2f51f9c053f43d8bd093e76f0cc6301b545549c998fa2&token=eaf2f51f9c053f43d8bd093e76f0cc6301b545549c998fa2
```

Copy and paste the URL in your local machine browser.

Comment: I don't believe this answers the question. He wants to run the notebook locally, as in the jupiter notebook on his personal laptop, and leverage the remote machine for processing. This answer runs both the notebook and execution on the remote machine.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to  access Jupyter/Ipython notebook running on a VPS remotely, I wrote a tutorial on the [digital ocean community site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-jupyter-notebook-to-run-ipython-on-ubuntu-16-04).

As shown in the guide, after installing and running Ipython Notebook using command line on the server, you can connect to the notebook using SSH tunnelling with Putty (on windows) or the ssh -L command on Unix-like systems (ie Mac and Linux)

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question. The question is about running Notebook _locally_ but to be able execute commands on the remote host. It is more like  https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel but running commands not in local shell but in remote shell via ssh.