# Jupyter notebook matlab kernel on remote machine

Tags: matlab, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I would like to package some of my MATLAB code in a Jupyter notebook, which I understand I can do using pymatbridge and the matlab_kernel for jupyter.

However, I don't have MATLAB on my local machine. I use ssh to connect to a remote machine and run MATLAB there.

I am able to start a Jupyter notebook after I ssh to the remote machine and I can see the option to start a MATLAB notebook. When I start it however I get a long list of errors in the terminal and the notebook does not respond when I try to run code. Can someone correct the procedure I have used to setup the MATLAB kernel for Jupyter?

I have anaconda 4.1.1 on my machine. This is the procedure I have used to setup the matlab kernel:

```
pip install pymatbridge
pip install matlab_kernel
python -m matlab_kernel install --user
```

As suggested here (https://anneurai.net/2015/11/12/matlab-based-ipython-notebooks/) I add the following to my .bash_profile to point the matlab kernel to matlab:

```
export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/opt/matlab-R2014a/bin/matlab
```

This is the path I get when I run 'which matlab' after I ssh to the remote machine.

This is the error I get in the terminal when I start a MATLAB notebook:

```
/home/s0822514/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/nbformat.py:13: ShimWarning: The `IPython.nbformat` package has been deprecated. You should import from nbformat instead.
"You should import from nbformat instead.", ShimWarning)
Invalid MEX-file
'/home/s0822514/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymatbridge/matlab/messenger.mexa64':
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by
 /home/s0822514/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymatbridge/matlab/messenger.mexa64)

Error in matlabserver (line 7)
messenger('init', socket_address);

[W 11:27:38.899 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from c8b74e6f-21f8-477a-bde7-5f10ff141089
Traceback (most recent call last):

[I've removed all the traceback info here because it is quite long, please comment if this is important]

ValueError: MATLAB failed to start
```

My guess is that the matlab_kernel is not installed correctly since when I first installed it there was an error requiring me to use sudo or add --user. Alternatively I think there is something wrong with how I am pointing the matlab_kernel to MATLAB in my bash profile.

My last thought is that maybe I should be doing everything, including setting up anaconda and the jupyter notebook on the remote machine (As is suggested here: [Use Jupyter Notebook on my local computer to run code on a remote computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399059/use-jupyter-notebook-on-my-local-computer-to-run-code-on-a-remote-computer)) But I have tried doing the procedure to setup the MATLAB kernel after I ssh to the remote machine. This does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: I think the problem might be with pymatbridge. If I do `from pymatbridge import Matlab`, `mlab = Matlab(executable = 'matlab')`, `mlab().start`

Comment: I think the problem might be with pymatbridge. If I do `from pymatbridge import Matlab`, I get the same error telling me that "`IPython.nbformat` package has been deprecated.". If I then do `mlab = Matlab(executable = 'matlab')`, `mlab().start` I get an error saying the Matlab object is not callable

Comment: I found this thread https://github.com/arokem/python-matlab-bridge/issues/221 suggesting that in order to get rid of the Invalid Mex file error I need to rebuild the "messenger" part of pymatbridge from source and install it again. Unfortunately I run in to the same problem as the user here that I would need root access to run `yum install zeromq-devel`