# Use Jupyter to run remotely without coping file(other than script) on remote computer

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

With the lockdown going on, I work on my professional laptop to run Machine Learning models. Sadly, this laptop is not very powerful.
Since I have a powerful machine at home, I wish to use it's power. I know it is [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399059/use-jupyter-notebook-on-my-local-computer-to-run-code-on-a-remote-computer), but the solution shown implies to copy files on the remote computer. I have restriction from my company that doesn't allow me to do so for security reasons.

Is there a way to still manage to use my home computer resources to run my code ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: why you are not using google colab? google also facilitate us to Free access to GPUs

Answer (score 1):

I do the same thing without copying the data using `WinSCP`. It's Data manager with GUI which works very similar to `PUTTY`. With this you can live synchronize folders in both machines, edit the files on your machine and test on the other. But for this trick you will need both Pycharm and Jupyter. Pycharm for editting functions with WinSCP and jupyter for testing the functions. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but synchronization of folders imply the transfer of data doesn't it ?

Comment: No your synchronizing the scripts. That means you are editting .py files from your working machine and they are getting editted live in your home machine where you have your data.

Comment: Right, but then, how does the remote machine access data files (other than script)  ? I might have not been very understandable, I apologize for that

Comment: For what it's worth, SCP stands for _Secure Copy Protocol_. This solution will not meet your company's security requirements.

Comment: ok I assume you understood the answe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35399059/use-jupyter-notebook-on-my-local-computer-to-run-code-on-a-remote-computer). you will run a jupyter notebook on your home machine with `jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8898` and on your working machine using `ssh -N -f -L 127.0.0.1:8898:127.0.0.1:8898 user@remote-machine.com` you will get access to that port. For this you need some sord of connection to ` user@remote-machine.com` which represents your home machine. you can get this using `putty` without GUI option or `WinSCP`with GUI option....

Comment: the second one gives you the option of live synchronizing with the scrips on your machine. that means you are editting on your working machine but through the connection and synchronization its like you are editting on your home machine. and thats how you can simply use the PATH of your data in your home machine in your script. But check if what @Andy said is true, cause in that case my solution wont help you.

Comment: @hamid.khb the issue is precisely with the file being edited on the home machine. Op requires the file not be on that machine at all.

Comment: Oh ok so just read my comment again and replace the home machine with office machine. in that case you are connecting your home machine with the one that has the data and using your home machine to train. but again the security meassure of the firm should allow you the possibility the connection.

Comment: Well it seems to me that your solution implies some sort of copy. 
Solutions that comes to my mind( but it might be not exhaustive) would be some sort of streaming of my files in my work computer(but would that be possible ? and would that be secure and allowed by work computer's firewall ? )  or (and I think more viable option) in some sort send the work to do (calculation) from work computer to home computer