# Is their some means of coding and running Python on a Raspberry PI from a PC?

Tags: python, .net, ssh, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

So far, SSH is all I can think of. Send a command line like `python <dosometing.`, and interpret the response. I am, however, hoping for a lower level library, where I can enter the Python command in my interpreter's REPL, and have that command execute on the Pi, and return the result to my REPL.

Please no questions why don't I just SSH straight into the Pi and use its Python directly. I don't want to use an SSH session to write Python on my headless Pi. I want a Windows Python REPL that talks to the Raspbian Python transpiler. This is for an experimental task that is part of a much larger project about .NET and Pi communication.

Comment: To get useful advise you should add more details about what you are trying to archive.

Comment: @KlausD, please see my edit.

Comment: I'd say you're looking for a higher-level approach than SSH, something that abstracts the user from where the code runs. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499074/run-local-python-script-on-remote-server for some possible approaches, maybe, using SSH under the hood to deliver code to the place it will execute.

Comment: Indeed, Paramiko looks very close to what I'm looking for. I've even marked this as a duplicate, so it has at least one literate's vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to my mind is to create a TCP server-client app. Server would reside on RPi, and waiting on connections. When the command arrives from client, server will execute it (using `subprocess.Popen` or even maybe `os.system`). Client can get whole output back (in the first case), or just exit status (in the second case).

Comment: Yes, that seems ideal, but I was hoping for a means to avoid rolling my own TCP based app.