# Run python code on remote python process

Tags: python

I have to run python code on remote python process.

Normally, what I would do is:

> ssh admin@localhost -p 61234

which opens a interactive python console and I can execute python code directly.

```
>>> print('3')
3
>>>
```

But I want to automate this and pass python code as parameter to ssh.

I tried following options:

> ssh admin@localhost -v -p 61234 python logs.py
>
> ssh admin@localhost -v -p 61234 nohup python logs.py
>
> ssh admin@localhost -p 61234 < logs.py
>
> cat logs.py | ssh admin@localhost -p 61234 python -

But all options give following error:

> shell request failed on channel 0

**logs.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# tried with and without first line.
print('3')
```

---

```
netstat -anp | grep 61234
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:61234         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6/python2.7
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499074/run-local-python-script-on-remote-server

Comment: Tried that too. Same error.

Comment: @Batty 'cat logs.py | ssh admin@localhost python -' without the -p 61234 part

Comment: do you have access to the remote machine's logs?

Comment: Sounds like a problem [mitogen](https://github.com/dw/mitogen) would solve.

Comment: try not to put  -p and it could work

Comment: Also, your second last option looks fine. Just add this `ssh admin@localhost python < ./logs.py`

Comment: All these options seem to run python script on `bash` on the machine but not on remote python process running on 61234 port.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is overkill, but who knows, maybe you need more than just a simple command in the future.

[Paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/) package is what you're looking for. The project is **full** of demos which demonstrate *how* and in many different ways.

The function you'll find the most useful is [paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.4/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.exec_command)

> Execute a command on the SSH server. A new Channel is opened and the
>   requested command is executed. The command’s input and output streams
>   are returned as Python file-like objects representing stdin, stdout,
>   and stderr.

[Demos Folder](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/demos)
[In-depth Testing](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/tests)
[Interactive.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/interactive.py) is a fully interactive TTY (remote terminal control functions).

Answer (score 0):

[PyCharm Professional Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/tools.html) (Python IDE from JetBrains) has tools for remote development, including SSH remoting, and the ability to run a remote interpreter:

[image]